# Convert a String to enum value in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, enums, model

Let us say that I have an enum:

```
enum XYZ { addition, updation, remove}
```

and I have a result string that I get using `fromJson` method which returns addition, updation or remove

How do I write a function so that these values get converted into the enum values. Something like `XYZ.json['result']` which should return me `XYZ.addition` or `XYZ.updation` and so on

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do this

```
String yourString = 'addition';
XYZ? result = XYZ.values.firstWhereOrNull((e) => e.name == yourString);
```

Note that `result` can be `null` if the string doesn't match any of them. You could write this to fall back to `XYZ.addition` for example

```
XYZ result = XYZ.values.firstWhereOrNull((e) => e.name == yourString) ?? XYZ.addition;
```

`firstWhereOrNull` is part of the `collection` package so you would need to add that and import it like:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivo. Just a small remark: I believe it is 'firstOrNullWhere' instead of 'firstWhereOrNull'

Comment: @raw no, what makes you think that?

Comment: Ok, well to keep it short: I guess you're right.

I was using [dartx](https://pub.dev/packages/dartx), where the method is called slightly differently. 

For your code to work (and I guess it is better to stick with the core libraries), I had to add:
$flutter pub add collection
and reference it 'import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

If that's correct, I hope this comment helps others.

Comment: @raw ah yes you're right. This does require the `collection` package. I'll edit it into the answer